# How can I remove a word if it's in another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I remove a word if it's in another cell?

Example:

- A1 contains `123 Main St Los Angeles`
- B1 contains `Los Angeles`

How can I remove Los Angeles from A1, if it's in B1?

Answer (score 1):

In C1 write:
`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,B1,"",1)`

Then copy C1 and paste special value in A1.
Substitute replace the text in B1 which is contained in A1 with ""

Answer (score 0):

1. click on column A
2. Go to tab `Data`
3. then click 'text to Columns'
4. Pick 'Fixed width' then next
5. adjust the columns to the space you want to cut the data
6. Click Finish

And Los Angeles should move into the next column. If you have text in Column B already, make sure to add a column first. If you wanted to split the street number from Main, you could have picked 'delimited' option, and have the column split by the first space.